# How to add pending changes or checkout files in TFVC programmatically (netstandard2.0)

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops, tfvc, .net-standard-2.0

The package we used before ([Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient)), doesn't support `netstandard2.0` and it seems that the new [REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops) doesn't support the tasks we want to accomplish either.

So what's the recommended way to add new files as pending changes or checkout existing files in tfvc when targeting `netstandard2.0`?

`TF.exe` should be capable of doing the aforementioned tasks, but to get the path to it we would somehow need `vsWhere.exe` and so that whole approach seems a little bit cumbersome.

Comment: The fact that Microsoft themselves no longer uses TFVC should give you a really big clue that it's no longer supported and will never ever be updated again. The fact that Microsoft themselves have moved to Git should give you a really big clue about what you should be doing with your repos.

Comment: @IanKemp Thx for your comment. Yeah I know, we are already moving a lot of things into git repositories, but we have a huge legacy tfvc mono-repo, that we can't move as easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no, and won't be, a .NET Core compatible version of the TFVC client object model. The API used to interact with TFVC is a SOAP based API and it has never been ported to REST.

You can use vswhere to find tf.exe or build a custom .NET 4.x executable using the Client Object Model and call from your .NET Core app.

You're allowed to redistribute a copy of vswhere with your application. You can grab the latest version from here:

```
    - powershell: |
        $vswhereLatest = "https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere/releases/latest/download/vswhere.exe"
        $vswherePath = "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\tools\vswhere.exe"
        remove-item $vswherePath
        invoke-webrequest $vswhereLatest -OutFile $vswherePath
        test-path $vswherePath -PathType Leaf
      displayName: 'Grab the latest version of vswhere.exe'
```

As you can see, I run this in my Azure Pipeline to inject the latest version into my build directory prior to packaging my app.

And this is the code I use do find `tf.exe` afterwards:

```
$path = & $PSScriptRoot/vswhere.exe -latest -products * `
  -requires Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamExplorer `
  -find "Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe"
```

Comment: The arguments for vswhere.exe could be even improved, so it results in a one-liner: `-latest -products * -requires Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamExplorer -find "**\Team Explorer\TF.exe"`

Comment: @roli09 thank for the update.  I find the `**` takes forever. So the exact path works a lot better :).